# why python cannot determine roots and use mark sweep?

Tags: python, garbage-collection

The idea is from [this reference](http://arctrix.com/nas/python/gc/).

> Because of the way extension modules work, Python can never fully determine the root set.

In my understanding, the Python interpreter operates similarly as JVM but probably more abstractly. So there are current executing frames and why root can't determined there? In terms of the C extension module, why not leave that alone and let it manage its memory itself?

Another interesting point is that

> First we observe that reference cycles can only be created by container objects.

Can't I create two custom classes and make them referencing each other? I thought a bit on this, seems not straight to construct one, but how to prove we can't construct this scenario by some fabricate constructions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extension modules handle raw object pointers (`PyObject *`) all the time, and some of them store such pointers in the weirdest locations (`static` variables, custom non-Python data structures, as payload data for a callback for some other library's event system, etc.), so it's far more than just the locals of the current stack frames that need to be examined. And even scanning the stack needs platform-specific assembly magic, as the page you refer to mentions.

It is possible to design an extension API that explicitly communicates all such pointers, but for CPython that ship has sailed twenty years ago, if it ever was an option to begin with (it's a big hassle for what many perceive to be a minor benefit).

> Can't I create two custom classes and make them referencing each other?

Read on. Here "container" is used in a rather broader sense:

> These are objects which can hold references to other objects. In Python lists, dictionaries, instances, classes, and tuples are all examples of container objects. Integers and strings are not containers.